# Is it possible to access the invert colors function that’s in iOS accessibility?

Tags: ios, swift

The function that Apple has already put in iOS that is in Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Invert colors, can I somehow use that in my program so for say when the user touches the screen the colors invert?

Comment: Are you talking about doing this *just* for your app or for the system as a whole? If it's the former, you will have to do this yourself. If the latter, you are out of luck as far as I know.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of a way to do this automatically, but you could invert colors yourself using an extension on UIColor and accessing the subviews?

```
extension UIColor {
    var inverted: UIColor {
        var r: CGFloat = 0.0, g: CGFloat = 0.0, b: CGFloat = 0.0, a: CGFloat = 0.0
        self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        return UIColor(red: (1 - r), green: (1 - g), blue: (1 - b), alpha: a) // Assuming you want the same alpha value.
    }
}
```

And then if you want to update specific properties of the views you could do something like this:

```
  view.subviews.map { $0.backgroundColor = $0.backgroundColor.invertedColor }
  // And so on to change things like the tint color, text color, etc.
```

Sorry, I don't know a way to do this directly but till then this is better than nothing I guess.

Comment: I have edited : just changed   `UIColor.red.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)`    into    `self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)`

Answer (score 1):

I know of no such API call, and frankly I'd be surprised if it was available. Generally, Apple does not provide system-wide settings to individual applications. However, you could implement this yourself—but only for your own app.

Answer (score 1):

Now this can be done with a buid-in method from SwiftUI; `colorInvert()`.

The `colorInvert()` modifier inverts all of the colors in a view so that each color displays as its complementary color. For example, blue converts to yellow, and white converts to black.

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/colorinvert()

Answer (score 0):

works in SwiftUI also:

```
extension NSColor {
    var inverted: NSColor {
        var r: CGFloat = 0.0, g: CGFloat = 0.0, b: CGFloat = 0.0, a: CGFloat = 0.0
        self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        return NSColor(red: (1 - r), green: (1 - g), blue: (1 - b), alpha: a)
    }
}

extension Color {
    var inverted: Color {
        Color(nsColor: self.nsColor.inverted)
    }
}

@available(macOS 12.0, *)
public extension Color {
    var nsColor: NSColor { NSColor(self) }
    var cgColor: CGColor { nsColor.cgColor }
}
```