# Setting IOS Accessibility Colors inversion programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, uiactionsheet

I´m relatively new to mobile development and I´m trying to set accessibility color invertion opion programmatically, in Swift. Anyone know if it´s possible?
Thanks!

Comment: why would you want to do that exactly?

Comment: I´m writing an app that has a PDF viewer. The documents that I need to show in the viewer are simple black and white pdf and I need To implement some kind of "night mode" on this viewer, inverting the PDF colors. I´ve googled a lot and couldn´t find a way to do that and I was thinking if I could use the accessibility options to do that, even if it would invert all the interface colors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639907/with-swift-is-it-possible-to-access-the-invert-colors-function-that-s-in-access

Answer (score 1):

Changing the accessibility settings on someone's device is not only impossible, but also very bad practice if somehow you managed to do it. You would affect their device even when outside of your application which would be incredible annoying. You need to implement a feature to change the PDF colors within the app only, possibly by modifying the background color and text font.